# Creating List definition for Survey list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-definition

I wanted to create a Survey List definition through visual Studio. But when i tried creating it - there was no option available to create list definition for Survey List

Please let me know how to go forward to create Survey List definition.

Thanks